# how to add a new function to Form Validation Class of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

i having a function called website_check

```
function website_check($url){
if ($url !=""){     
    if (preg_match("#^https?://.+#", $url) and fopen($url,"r")){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('Website url', 'The %s field is invalid');
        return FALSE;
    }       
}else{
    $this->form_validation->set_message('Website url', 'The %s field is required');
    return FALSE;
}
```

}

and i use this function as a custom code-igniter form validation function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website', 'callback_website_check');
```

i am using this function in every controller, so i want to add this function into codeigniters form validation class and use as a default validation function. is it possible to add your function to codeigniters form validation class,if it is how it can be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the file 'system/libraries/Form_validation.php' and insert this new function to the class "CI_Form_validation".

```
function website_check($url){  
   if (preg_match("#^https?://.+#", $url) and fopen($url,"r")){
      return TRUE;
   }else{
      return FALSE;
   }       
}
```

And then edit the file 'language/english/form_validation_lang.php' and append this item:

```
$lang['website_check'] = "The %s field is invalid";
```

then use it as :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('website', 'Website', 'website_check');
```

Comment: It's bad practice to alter the system files, especially when you don't have to. See markle's reply.

Comment: CodeIgniter allows edit and modification in the source code, please review the license link: 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/license.html

Comment: Sure they _allow_ it. It's your code. But it's considering bad practice since if the user gets a problem, his problem might be in the `system` folder, thus giving a risk for different result for the ones who tries to help him and all documentation may be unreliable. CodeIgniter has done a great job allowing extensions to avoid this, therefor markle's approach is considered best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Create a file in the application/library directory called MY_Form_validation.php. Make the class name MY_Form_validation as well. Be sure that it extends CI_Form_validation, and that it calls the parent constructor. Then, add your rules as methods:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function website_check($url)
{
    if ($url != "") {     
        if (preg_match("#^https?://.+#", $url) and fopen($url,"r")) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }       
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}

}
```

You will also need to add the rule to the form_validation_lang.php file (in application/language/en). Just add a rule to the bottom like this:

```
$lang['website_check']      = "The %s field is invalid.";
```

If the file doesn't exist you can copy it from the system/language folder. You shouldn't edit files in the system folder as they will be overwritten when you update.